# Altium: make a specific GND pad not to connect to GND pour

Tags: pcb-design, altium

I have a 2 layer board design and I'm using the top layer for traces and ground plane.

Then I have an ADC and the -Vin pin is connected to a connector and both of them to GND but I want the -Vin pin to have one and only connection to GND through the connector pad but Vin- is being connected to the GND plane also. How can this be done?

I know that I could use a cutout but I'm asking for alternatives.

[image]

Comment: Google "Altium Net-Tie" and pick the tutorial that best fits you.

Comment: Thanks, I've just checked a tutorial but I'd better use a cutout rather than the net-tie, honestly. I was expecting something like any kind of rule

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Im thinking one of the following approaches could do the job:

**Cutout**

Simplest solution.

**Block path for plane**

place an object with a different net next to the pin to block the ground polygon from reaching the pad

**Rule**

under design - rules - plane- polygon connect style: add a rule that excludes this part. Apply the rule to ALL and InComponent('putDesignatorHere') (or: InComponent('') AND InNet('GND'). Then set the connect style to 'no connect'. This ofc would also remove the other ground connection from the plane

*as mentioned by Tom L.* you can also address a specified pad in the rules using HasPad('IC3-3')

**Different nets**

Probably the cleanest solution: Give this Ground a different net name (eg VSSA), create a net tie object and then connect GND and VSSA with help of the net tie.

Comment: I like the rule approach and I feel that it's cleaner than the net tie one. I can deal with the other GND pad by using a via.

Comment: Yes via or just a trace. As long as no one else could work on that project later (who may not be aware of the rule and wonder, why the pad wont connect to the plane) I think the rule approach is awesome. For shared projects a net tie is more obvious/clean to others.

Comment: You can use the 'HasPad('IC3-3')' to target that pad explicitly. No need for a workaround.

Comment: Maybe @L.Heinrichs wants to add that to his collection?